# How do i customise a date picker interface in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a design i am trying o replicate in flutter which a user can be able to select date from a dropdown

[image: Desired design]

The design is not a problem, however what is the problem is the logic.

How do i Implement this?

I tried looking for flutter packages to help and i found one closest to my need which is [datepicker_dropdown](https://pub.dev/packages/datepicker_dropdown).

But the only issue with this package is that it doesn't have an option for margin as all the boxes are two close to each other which then alters the desired design

I also tried using some other date picker packages but then the problem is...

How do i get to automatically fill in the dropdown fields of my the design to be filled when a date is picked using any date picker?

Any idea of how to implement this design would be helpful. Thanks!

This is an update to the current situation ( code and output screen added )

```html
class StartAJobView extends GetView<AuthController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(EServiceFormController());
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: Helper().onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Start a job".tr,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Color(0xff151515))),
          centerTitle: false,
          leadingWidth: 15,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                size: 20, color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        ),
        body: StartAJobForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StartAJobForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartAJobForm({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      //key: controller.registerStepTwoFormKey,
      child: ListView(
        primary: true,
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Divider(
                          color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.1),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, top: 20),
                            child: Text(
                              'Enter job details to begin',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: Color(0xff151515)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5, left: 22, right: 22),
                            child: Text(
                              'Enter the details of  your agreement with a customer to start a job',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                color: Color(0xff596780),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 24,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 22.0,
                  right: 22.0,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        offset: Offset(0, 2),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                    //initialValue: controller.currentUser?.value?.name,
                    // onSaved: (input) =>
                    //     controller.currentUser.value.name = input,
                    validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                        ? "Should be more than 3 characters".tr
                        : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
                      hintText: 'Asoebi Gown ',
                      label: Text('Job Title'),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3498DB), width: 1.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        offset: Offset(0, 2),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                    //initialValue: controller.currentUser?.value?.name,
                    // onSaved: (input) =>
                    //     controller.currentUser.value.name = input,
                    validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                        ? "Should be more than 3 characters".tr
                        : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
                      hintText: '2',
                      label: Text('Quantiy of items '),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3498DB), width: 1.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        offset: Offset(0, 2),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,

                    cursorColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                    //initialValue: controller.currentUser?.value?.name,
                    // onSaved: (input) =>
                    //     controller.currentUser.value.name = input,
                    validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                        ? "Should be more than 3 characters".tr
                        : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff596780),
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      hintText:
                          ' She wants to sew \n 1. An off shoulder asoebi gown (purple) with \n front slit, corset and stoning. \n 2. dinner gown, V neck, long with slit (black)',
                      hintMaxLines: 5,
                      label: Text('Job description'),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 20, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3498DB), width: 1.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        offset: Offset(0, 2),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                    //initialValue: controller.currentUser?.value?.name,
                    // onSaved: (input) =>
                    //     controller.currentUser.value.name = input,
                    validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                        ? "Should be more than 3 characters".tr
                        : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
                      hintText: 'Ajoke Sanusi Fafunwa',
                      label: Text('Customer Name'),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3498DB), width: 1.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FadeInDown(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                      validator: (input) =>
                          !input.contains('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0')
                              ? "Should be a valid phone number".tr
                              : null,
                      onInputChanged: (Value) {},
                      // onSaved: (input) => controller.currentUser.value
                      //     .phoneNumber = input as String,
                      formatInput: false,
                      selectorConfig: SelectorConfig(
                        selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.DROPDOWN,
                        useEmoji: true,
                      ),
                      cursorColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                      inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 0),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Customer phone number',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 22),
                  child: Text(
                    'When should this be completed',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Color(0xff151515),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                child: DropdownDatePicker(
                  inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  isDropdownHideUnderline: true,
                  isFormValidator: true,
                  startYear: 1900,
                  endYear: 2020,
                  width: 10,
                  selectedMonth: 10,
                  selectedYear: 1993,
                  onChangedDay: (value) => print('onChangedDay: $value'),
                  onChangedMonth: (value) => print('onChangedMonth: $value'),
                  onChangedYear: (value) => print('onChangedYear: $value'),
                ),
              ),
              FadeInDown(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      cursorColor: Color(0xff3498DB),
                      // initialValue:
                      //     controller.currentUser?.value?.email,
                      // onSaved: (input) =>
                      //     controller.currentUser.value.email = input,
                      validator: (input) => input.length < 10
                          ? "Should be more than 10 characters".tr
                          : null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 15, left: 5, right: 0, bottom: 15),
                          child: new SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                            child: Image.asset('assets/icon/geolocation.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Business Address ',
                        label: Text('Business Address'),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3498DB), width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              FadeInDown(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22),
                  child: Container(
                    // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    //   color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                    //   boxShadow: [
                    //     BoxShadow(
                    //       color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                    //       blurRadius: 10,
                    //       offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    //     ),
                    //   ],
                    //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    //   border: Border.all(
                    //     color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                    child: CSCPicker(
                      onCountryChanged: (country) {},
                      onStateChanged: (state) {},
                      onCityChanged: (city) {},
                      countryDropdownLabel: 'Select Country',
                      stateDropdownLabel: 'Select State',
                      cityDropdownLabel: 'Select Town',
                      citySearchPlaceholder: 'Search Town',
                      dropdownDialogRadius: 20,
                      searchBarRadius: 20,
                      dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          ),
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                        ),
                      ),
                      selectedItemStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff212121),
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                child: FadeInDown(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Get.toNamed(Routes.PHONE_VERIFICATION);
                    },
                    color: Color(0xff34495E),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.18),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    child: Text(
                      'Next',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my output with error :

[image: Output screen]

[image: Error details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

Add `datepicker_dropdown: ^0.0.7+3` in your pubspec.yaml file

import below library in your code file:

```
import 'package:datepicker_dropdown/datepicker_dropdown.dart';
```

Your Widget:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
          child: DropdownDatePicker(
            inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            isDropdownHideUnderline: true,
            isFormValidator: true,
            startYear: 1900,
            endYear: 2020,
            width: 10,
            dayFlex: 1,
            monthFlex: 1,
            yearFlex: 1,
            isExpanded: true,
            selectedMonth: 10,
            selectedYear: 1993,
            onChangedDay: (value) => print('onChangedDay: $value'),
            onChangedMonth: (value) => print('onChangedMonth: $value'),
            onChangedYear: (value) => print('onChangedYear: $value'),
          ),
        ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you sir, but unfortunately it gives me a renderflex error because i need spacing around it so i had to wrap it with padding... do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: Add your code and output screen

Comment: I just did sir. Thank you for your time

Comment: @tesseract please check my updated answer hope its help to you.

Comment: It worked! Never knew i could use flex parameters! Thank you! Another thing sir:  is there a way i can make day to appear first before month?

Comment: @tesseract I will try tomorrow please give me time.

Comment: Okay! I appreciate, i will also try to to remind you tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251090/discussion-between-tesseract-and-ravindra-s-patil).

Comment: @tesseract I have lots of try but not found proper solution for `Day Month Year` format, I think as per [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/datepicker_dropdown) says  this `datepicker_dropdown` format is `Month Day Year` am founding the proper solution on your expectation if its work then I will ping you.